# mpandroidchart I want to get 3rd value

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am using mpandroidchart and i have a problem now

I set 3 values into the array likes this
(index, values, and another value)

```
ArrayList<Entry> value1 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
        float y = (float) Math.random();
        float h = (float) Math.random();
        value1.add(new Entry(i, y, h));
        }
```

I want to get h values to use this h

but i cant' find the way

How can i get h value?

Thanks for reading

***Edited ***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuUKs.png)

This is the image i want to make

*** Edited2 ***

```
ArrayList<Integer> color;
        ArrayList<Entry> value1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
            float y = (float) Math.random();
            value1.add(new Entry(i, y));
            if(y>10)
            {
                color.add(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            }
            else
                color.add(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }
        dataSet.setColors(color);
```

Dear M.Saad Lakhan
You suggested like upper code, But there are some ploblems.

1. ArrayList color; 
   -> "variable 'color' might not have been initiallized
2. color.add(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
   -> cannot resolve symbol 'context'
3. ArrayList dataSets = new ArrayList<>(); //this is my code
   dataSets.setColors(color);
   -> there is no setColors in my datasets

What are these problem?

Comment: Which chart are you implementing? If you are looking for barchart may be you need to implement stacked bar chart.

Comment: in my case, i want to use for scatter chart

Comment: Which version of library you are using?

Comment: You need to add 3rd value ? Why do you need 3rd value? For labels or colors ? Because to entry you can provide two values and if you need third value then you need another array list to do your job? Let me know if you need that h value for labels or colors I will tell you how to implement that.

Comment: x and y are displayed on the graph to indicate their position, and h want to let them know something is wrong at that position. for example, in

Comment: for example, in (0,0,0) case on the x-y grpah (0,0) bluecolor dot and 
in (1,1,10) case (1,1) redColor

Comment: Sorry for my poor english.... Can you understand?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope this helps. And where you are creating your datasets just before chart.invalidate() add dataset.setColors(colors);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create:

```
ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
```

After that you need to add values for each entry which color you want to show, you need to modify your code as:

```
ArrayList<Entry> value1 = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{  
   float y = (float) Math.random();
   value1.add(new Entry(i, y));
// add your condition here
if(y>10)
 {
   color.add(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
 }
else
   color.add(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
}
```

When you complete your colors arraylist then you can set colors as:

```
dataSet.setColors(color);
```

Comment: This will work. Happy coding :). For further assistance do let me know mate ! And dont forget to mark this as answer if that works for you.

Comment: thanks for replying, but it doesn't work. there is no setColors in my case ;(
i declare ArrayList<IScatterDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>(); like this.
what's problem?

Comment: For further assistance please show me your code where you are creating chart.

Comment: it doesn't work still ;( How can i show you my code?

Comment: I changed getContext() -> getBaseContext() and change setColor's locatioin
and it works
I really really thanks to you

Comment: Its my pleasure to help you mate. Happy coding :)