# mpandroidchart i want to change dot color by some value in scatter chart

Tags: mpandroidchart

I want to make a scatter chart

It has a not x,y value but another value that change dot color

if its value over some value

Only i have found was

[MPAndroidChart, set different color to bar in a bar chart based on y axis values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888850/mpandroidchart-set-different-color-to-bar-in-a-bar-chart-based-on-y-axis-values)

this.

But in my case, there is a special value that not effect on the graph

What can i do to solve this problem?

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create ArrayList of third values for each entry after that you need to add following code to change colors respectively:

```
dataSet.setColors(new int[]{R.color.color1 , R.color.color2} , context);
```

Comment: Hi I can't use setColors. I will edit my question. Can you fix it for me?

Comment: Yes I will love to help you so what you want then ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977571/mpandroidchart-i-want-to-get-3rd-value

Comment: check this problem please

Comment: Ok I have edited my answer implement changes as I described there